# costumed query in wordpress category.php

Tags: wordpress, categories

I create category.php for display categories archive in a costumed template.

In a category page link like this: http://www.example.com/category/cat1/

By these codes it's OK and shows last items of **cat1**

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
// Some template code
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But when I try to customize query by **WP_Query** or **query_posts** instead of contents of **cat1** it shows contents of all categories of site

```
    <?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=30' ); ?>    
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    // Some template code
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

What is reason and solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define cat in your query.

it's your answer:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
        'posts_per_page' => 30
);
$recent = new WP_Query($args); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
 //some template code

<?php endwhile; ?>
```